# Array in command Button VBA

Tags: vba

I'm doing a code where, when i click button 1, it will load the array form the `range B8:C17`, and when I click button 2, it should print the array in `range E8:F17`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
arr = Range("B8:C17")
Range("B8:C17") = Clear
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("E8:F17") = arr

End Sub
  
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Dim arr As Variant

End Sub
```

The button 1 works fine but the button 2 does not. What did I do wrong here ?

Comment: the variable `arr` in the first sub is filled, when it ends VBA clears it. So in the second sub is empty. You should merge the code in a single sub.

Comment: Well since your using a userform you should be able to just declare your array publicly to allow it to retain it's values while the userform is open. To do this, add `Public arr As Variant` to the top of your userform module (outside of a sub) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In your code = Clear will yield an error, it should be used as method like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public arr

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  arr = Range("B8:C17")
  Range("B8:C17").Clear
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Range("E8:F17") = arr
End Sub


'Private Sub UserForm_Click()
'
'End Sub
```

[image]